# Is there a way to inspect network connections on Play Store Apps?

Tags: android

For example, I want to download an app from the play store, and inspect any outgoing and incoming network connections, like in the `network` tab of most browsers. How would one go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4):

In short - use [Burp](https://portswigger.net/support/configuring-an-android-device-to-work-with-burp#:%7E:text=In%20Burp%2C%20go%20to%20the%20%22Proxy%20Intercept%22%20tab%2C,to%20toggle%20the%20interception%20status). or some other similar tool. With http traffic it is easy as that - setup and intercept.

###### HTTPS however is more complicated:

On Android 6 and below you can do this by adding a new certificate as a trusted one in android settings. Then any software (for example Burp, [here is how](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/how-to-debug-https-traffic-for-android-apps-with-burp-proxy)) can just intercept and decode whole network traffic.

On Android 7 and up it's no longer possible. Apps only trust the system certificates by default, ignoring user provided ones. App can specify in `network_security_config.xml` that they trust the user certificates, but you cannot do that on external installed app. The app itself have to declare that. So basically to intercept https traffic on android 7 you have to hack into system certificates store (only doable with root i believe). You can get around that though by repackaging the apk file and adding custom `network_security_config.xml` that declares trust in user specified certificates [here is how](https://hurricanelabs.com/blog/modifying-android-apps-to-allow-tls-intercept-with-user-cas/).